# How to apply persist data when clicking from Vuetify Data Table?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Our application shows several thousand users in a Vuetify data able. We can search and sort to find users. Then, we can click on a user's name to open their profile.

The problem is that when we click "back" in the browser, the search/sort/pagination from the table is gone and we have to start over. It's really annoying when we are trying to look at lots of users very quickly.

What is the proper way to make the table not "reset" each time the page loads?

EDIT: We were able to get it working using keep-alive. See the App.vue code below...

Our table code. The Name cell has the link to the user profile page.

```
<v-data-table
    v-bind:headers="headers"
    :items="users"
    :search="search"
    :rows-per-page-items="[10,25]"
    >
    <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <td>
            <img v-if="props.item.photoUrl" :src="props.item.photoUrl" class="user-img">
            <img v-if="!props.item.photoUrl" src="/static/avatar.png" class="user-img">
        </td>
        <td>
            <router-link v-if="props.item.name" v-bind:to="'/staff/' + props.item.id">{{ props.item.name }}</router-link>
            <router-link v-if="!props.item.name" v-bind:to="'/staff/' + props.item.id">{{ props.item.id }}</router-link>
        </td>
        <td>{{ props.item.validState | round | percentage }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.averageScore }}</td>



        <td>{{ props.item.standing }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.phone}}</td>
        <td>
            <span v-if="props.item.tipsUrl">Yes</span>
        </td>
        <td>{{ props.item.city }}</td>
    </template>
    <template slot="pageText" slot-scope="{ pageStart, pageStop }">
        From {{ pageStart }} to {{ pageStop }}
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

App.vue keep-alive solution:

```
<template>
<v-app light>
<v-content>
  <transition name="router-anim">
    <keep-alive include="Event Reports,Users,Event Checkin,Event Jobs,Event Grades">
    <router-view/>
    </keep-alive>
  </transition>
</v-content>
```

Comment: there are two way to resolve your issues:
1.use route query params to store your search/sort/pagination infomation
2. use vuex to store your search/sort/pagination infomation and the result data

Comment: Yeah those two approaches make sense. I searched around to try and find any working examples to use a a starting point but no luck.

Comment: Can you wrap relevant components inside `<keep-alive>` tags? https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive I think it should work for a `back` option.

Comment: Awesome thank you! I was able to get it working and updated the code above